# how to make pandas.to_datetime convert large years in Python (Pandas)?

Tags: python, date, time, pandas

I have a dataset where some dates' year is exceptionally large.
Why does `type(pd.to_datetime('23/12/9999 12:00:00 AM'))` outputs: `str` whereas `type(pd.to_datetime('23/12/1999 12:00:00 AM'))` outputs `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`?

is there a limit to `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` ?
What am I missing?

Thanks,
HS

Comment: just found that `pd.tslib.Timestamp.max` outputs `Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807', tz=None)`
Is there any workaround?

Comment: [PeriodIndex](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#periodindex-and-period-range) can represent longer timespans than DatetimeIndex.

Comment: according to Numpy documentation, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html if the units are seconds the range is [ 2.9e9 BC, 2.9e9 AD] but when I try to force the units it doesn't help. Is Numpy datetime64 the same as Pandas timestamp?

Comment: pandas uses np.datetime64[ns] they are not the same; you cannot force units. if u really have that date repr the use PeriodIndex as Ed suggests. If they represent missing values then force parsing with coerce=True and they will become NaT

Comment: how do I test for NaT?

Comment: ``pd.isnull()`` will test for NaT (its by default counted as missing on a datetime64[ns] object)

Comment: can you please give an example how to used PeriodIndex to parse the above dates?